# How to specify conda requirement file?

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I'd like create virtualenv with conda. But it looks like I don't need to include the builtin packages in requirements. Because the virtualenv can use that directly. So the question, if I have some packages which is not conda builtin, how can I generate the requirement fiel that only contains these non-built-in packages ? Thanks

Comment: [This](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) should give you the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this cmd to install any packages not builtin to your conda environment:

```
conda install -n myenv <package>
```

To generate the requirement file, you can try:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```